# Cannot find lit after installing it

Tags: python, llvm

I'm trying to install lit by running:

```
python pip install lit
```

I got the successful message:

> Collecting lit
>   Installing collected packages: lit
>   Successfully installed lit-0.6.0

However, `which lit` returns nothing.

Comment: `pip show lit` is what you want; `which` is only for executable commands on the current path

Comment: @Hamms Sorry, I still do not get. So how can I find lit then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```
pip install lit --user
```

Output:

```
Collecting lit
Installing collected packages: lit
Successfully installed lit-0.6.0
```

Then, to see where the library is installed.
Input:

```
pip show lit
```

Output:

```
Name: lit
Version: 0.6.0
Summary: A Software Testing Tool
Home-page: http://llvm.org
Author: Daniel Dunbar
Author-email: daniel@minormatter.com
License: BSD
Location: /home/bill/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

The last line of the above output shows the directory where the library is installed.
Input:

```
cd /home/bill/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ls
```

Output:

```
BooleanExpression.py   __init__.py     LitTestCase.pyc  ProgressBar.pyc  ShUtil.py      Test.pyc
BooleanExpression.pyc  __init__.pyc    llvm     run.py       ShUtil.pyc     TestRunner.py
discovery.py           LitConfig.py    main.py      run.pyc      TestingConfig.py   TestRunner.pyc
discovery.pyc          LitConfig.pyc   main.pyc     ShCommands.py    TestingConfig.pyc  util.py
formats            LitTestCase.py  ProgressBar.py   ShCommands.pyc   Test.py        util.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start it as a command line interface, try this:

```
python -m lit.main
```

Answer (score 0):

Its binary is installed in `$HOME/.local/bin` which may not be included into `$PATH`. So set:

```sh
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

and then you can use `lit` in terminal.